# Insert value in div replacement jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
function getProductAttribute(event)
{    
    checkboxID = '#' + (domElement.attr('rel'));

    $("div[rel=$checkboxID").removeClass('on').addClass('off');    
}

<div class="off" rel="group_6" onclick="getProductAttribute(event);"></div>
```

This is not working, I hope someone can help me. I need the `$("div[rel=group_6")`

I can't use `$('.off).live('click', function () { }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

replace `$("div[rel=$checkboxID")` with `$("div[rel=" + checkboxID + "]")`

also you can replace `.removeClass('on').addClass('off')` with `.toggleClass("on" "off")` [see here](http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/).

Comment: Don't forget the closing square bracket! It should be `$("div[rel=" + checkboxID + "]")`

Answer (score 0):

This will get it working:

JS

```
function getProductAttribute(event) {
    checkboxID = $(event.srcElement).attr('rel');
    $('div[rel="'+checkboxID+'"').removeClass('on').addClass('off');
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="on" rel="group_6" onclick="getProductAttribute(event);"></div>
```

Example here: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sTcUr/)